# Shouldn't treeMap.entrySet() return a SortedSet?

Tags: java, collections

Why don't the [*treeMap.entrySet()*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet--) and [*treeMap.keySet()*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet--) methods return [*SortedSet*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)? I might go so far as saying that is a mistake. As per the API, a [*Set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is defined as not having a particular ordering. However, the sets returned by TreeMap **do** have a particular ordering.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't return a `SortedSet` (I guess you meant `TreeSet` there)?

Comment: @RohitJain That is what the API says.

Comment: API just says that it would return the `Set` view. What the actual `Set` implementation it returns is not there, and shouldn't be there. That's implementation detail.

Comment: @RohitJain no. (as per api): Sets do not have ordering. (as per api): treeMap.entrySet() returns a Set that has ordering.

Comment: `HashSet` don't have ordering (that is an implementation of `Set`). However, `TreeSet` do have ordering (that is again an implementation of `Set`). So, you don't know which set you get. Just you know that you get a `Set` which have keys in ascending order.

Comment: Note that `TreeMap` also has `navigableKeySet()` which returns a `NavigableSet` view of its keys.  In Oracle's implementation, `keySet()` delegates to `navigableKeySet()`

Comment: Thanks for all those who pointed out that covariant return types are permitted. I have deleted my inaccurate answer.

Comment: Part of this is that the `Comparator<Entry<K, V>>` would be slightly weird.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's a really good point. The only sane way to do it is to compare keys and ignore the values. It's not consistent with equals, but it doesn't break the contract for `compare`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think if they wrote the interface `SortedMap` now, both `keySet` and `entrySet` would return `SortedSet`. However, the `SortedMap` interface was introduced in Java 1.2 before covariant return types were allowed. They cannot change this now as there will be implementations of `SortedMap` out there for which `keySet` and `entrySet` returns a `Set` that is *not* a `SortedSet`.

Comment: Even though it is not a SortedSet, it does in fact define that the Set returned is in ascending order, as is defined in the javadoc of the SortedMap interface.